# Are these senteces the same in meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I had a warm discussion on the web with a folk on the expressions below:

1. It is true that I like it.
2. I truly like it.
3. I really like it.

My point is sentence 1,2,3 express the same meaning, while another folk thinks sentence 1 is different or not quite the same from sentence 2 & 3.

So, I hope to get out of the confusion here. Can someone help to weigh in with your thought? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is true that I like it.

This sentence conveys that the speaker is affirmative about liking a thing.

> I truly like it.
>
> I really like it

These sentences however, convey an additional emphasis on the liking part.

So, Sentence 1 is different from the others based on emphasizing while the other two sentences are virtually the same